# Shift+End Combo on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard

How can I change the settings for OS X Lion so that the combination of Shift+End results in the selection of text from the current cursor position to the end of the current line?  Specifically, I would like to be able to do this in Firefox, but if there is a general method that works for most/all applications, that would be ideal.

Comment: You may be interested in Nathan Greenstein's screencast that goes through how to be an OS X ninja with keyboard shortcuts and text: http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/keyboard-ninja-working-with-text-screencast/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a default key binding to perform this function: <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>⌃ (control)</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>.

If this won't serve, you may be interesting in Jacob Rus: [Customizing the Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) which provides instructions for creating your own keybindings dictionary.

See also:
Apple Mac OS X Developer Library:[Text System Defaults and Key Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html)
Ask Different: [DefaultKeyBinding.dict - old-style NeXT format vs XML plist format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/25051/11791)

Comment: I'd rather do it the Mac way, so thanks for educating me on that.  I'm still transitioning from Windows.  That said, I am interested in the keybindings info as well, so thanks for that.

Comment: I think you made the right call. Remapping the bindings gets into areas that make me uncomfortable—and drive you crazy when you're used to a custom set up but have to use someone's *stock* computer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save a property list like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLine:;
    "\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLine:;
    "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:;
    "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:;
}
```

The custom keybindings are currently not supported by Firefox though.